# Get list from dictionary with list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My data is organized like this:

```
d={1: [44, 56.5238], 2: [63, 56.8663], 3: [93, 55.7313], 4: [112, 55.5425]}
```

I want to create list with first values in these small lists:

```
new_list=[44, 63, 93, 112]
```

My ugly way to do it:

```
new_list=[]
for item in d.values():
    new_list.append(item[0])
```

Can I do it in better and shorter way, may be in one line?

Comment: With a _list comprehension_. However, what version of Python do you use? If it's less than 3.6 then you will have added complications in both approaches (if the output order is important)

Comment: `new_list = [item[0] for item in d.values()]`?

Comment: @pault, it works.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new_list = [d[key][0] for key in d]`

That's a list comprehension -- it loops throught the keys in `d`, and then gets the first item of each value, using that key.

Comment: you can add conditionals in a comprehension as well -- for instance: `new_list = [d[key][0] for key in d if type(key) == int and key % 2 == 0]`

that'll only grab the even numbered key if it's an integer.